# Upload size problem in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am uploading files to a MySql DB through PHP.
I am able to upload files upto 1MB size (found out by trial and error).
Files greater than 1 MB in size are not getting uploaded.
The MySql error printed by mysql_error() function in PHP is:
MySQL server has gone away

Can anybody please help me with this?
The MySql server is up and running only for requests > 1MB it is giving this error.

Regards,
Mayank.

P.S.:
I am using a form to upload the file.
`<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="fileUpload.php" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="MAX_FILE_SIZE" VALUE="300000000">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="action" VALUE="upload">
Description: <TEXTAREA NAME="txtDescription" ROWS="1" COLS="80"></TEXTAREA>
<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="binFile" ID="binFile">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Upload" VALUE="Upload">
</FORM>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sql query probably exceeds the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) size in which case the server will disconnect.
You might be interested in [mysqli_stmt::send_long_data](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data) which allows you to send parameters longer than max_allowed_packet in chunks.

Update: "How can i change it? Is using mysqli is the only option?"
Afaik the value can't be altered on a per-session base, i.e. if you cannot change the server configuration (my.cnf or startup parameters) the value will be read-only. edit: As the comment suggests you can change the global value of the mysql server after it has been started if you have [the proper permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super). 
PDO/PDO_MYSQL (as of phpversion 5.3.0) doesn't *seem* to support send_long_data, but I'm not sure about that either. That would leave [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) as the only option. I've recently noticed that [Wez Furlong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149111/wez-furlong) joined stack overflow. Since he is one of the authors of the PDO implementation he might know (though he did not write the pdo_*mysql* module).

(Completely untested and ugly) example

```
// $mysqli = new mysqli(....
$fp = fopen($_FILES['binFile']['tmp_name'], 'rb') or die('!fopen');

//$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT @@max_allowed_packet') or die($mysqli->error);
//$chunkSize = $result->fetch_all();
//$chunkSize = $maxsize[0][0];
$chunkSize = 262144; // 256k chunks

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO foo (desc, bindata) VALUES (?,?)') or die($mysqli->error);
// silently truncate the description to 8k
$desc = 8192 < strlen($_POST['txtDescription']) ? $_POST['txtDescription'] : substr($_POST['txtDescription'], 0, 8192);
$stmt->bind_param('sb', $desc, null);

while(!feof($fp)) {
  $chunk = fread($fp, $chunkSize);
  $stmt->send_long_data(1, $chunk) or die('!send_long_data.'.$stmt->error);
}
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi  Volker,
max_allowed_packet size is 1MB by default, I think that is the problem.
How can i change it? Is using mysqli is the only option?
Regards,
Mayank.

Comment: Hi Volker, 
I did it by altering the max_allowed_packet by using 
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16*1024*1024; // sets to 16MB

Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Mayank.

Answer (score 4):

In order to upload large files to your server with PHP, you need to change 2 parameters in your php.ini file.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 50M
```

50M = 50Mb

Comment: That doesn't account for the "MySQL server has gone away" message.

Comment: True. But i'd start with this first.

Comment: This would also manifest itself as either UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE or UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL in $_FILES['binFile']['error'], see 
http://php.net/features.file-upload.errors

Comment: I have changed the above 2 values to 50M but still i cant upload files larger than a few KB(20/30) what is wrong?