# How should I store music files?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to store uploaded files (sound, pictures and video)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186656/where-to-store-uploaded-files-sound-pictures-and-video)

I am making a website where the user registers and signs in and then they can upload their own music files. Should I store the music files that they upload as a blob in a MySQL DB table? or how else could I possibly store the files so they can be played through an HTML 5 media player? I have tried researching this online and all I can find is that it wouldn't be good to store the files in a MySQL table.

Comment: the *file* system is for *files*

Comment: what file system? I'm a beginner when it comes to all of this...

Answer (score 1):

Yous should upload them into a directory on your server. You associate a file name and or id with the song and user to retrieve them from the database when needed.

Comment: what if I only want the user that uploaded the songs to be able to listen to them? like I want them to be completely private to everyone but whoever uploaded them, sorry I forgot to add that part

Comment: @worm use the DB to track what songs/IDs someone has access to

Comment: Same concept. You have to write the logic that associates the user to the song.

Comment: store them outside the web root and server them via a script

Comment: private to somebody is not related to how to store your music. usually we store music into files in the server to maintain them more easily

Comment: @ernie are you saying to give each song an id and then store in the user DB what id's a certain user can access?

Comment: @worm exactly; the ID would be tied to a location on disk, and each user in your DB would have a list of IDs they could access.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to storing the media file, best to store them on the server somewhere, or even better store them on a CDN.

In regards to storing the details of the music, create a table in your mysql, call it something like music_meta and then save details about the files location, name, size etc.